# How to create a docker image of a compiled program?

Tags: docker

So I have a big program that I compiled on my computer and I would like to create a docker image of it in order to use it on other platform. How should I do it ? Should I just `COPY . .` in my dockerfile then add `./my_program` for the entrypoint ? 
How should I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't the right process be to compile this program into your image ? like this you will avoid missing dependencies etc

Answer (score 1):

There are many blogs on how to do this.  Here is a [Hacker Noon](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-dockerize-any-application-b60ad00e76da) article which explains the basic process.

For this to work, your image must contain all of the runtime dependencies for your application.  Depending on the technology you are using, this could be a little or a lot.

The basic steps are the following:

> 1. Choose a base image
> 2. Install the necessary packages
> 3. Add your custom files
> 4. Define which user will (or can) run your container
> 5. Define the exposed ports
> 6. Define the entrypoint
> 7. Define a configuration method

A basic example might look something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get install -y libssl1.1 libc6-amd64

COPY my_program /

RUN useradd my_user

USER my_user

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT "/my_program"
```